# How to implement vaults/libraries/workspaces of data in a database?

Tags: database-design

This question is inspired by vaults in ObsidianMD and the virtual libraries of calibre. I am building an application similar to calibre and I want to mimic the virtual library feature.

For those who are unfamiliar with the names I just used, think of workspaces or different desktops. Now imagine that I have several files that I have recorded in my database. Each of these files comes withs its own tags, categories, etc. Therefore each 'workspace' has its own files and tags and categories attributed to it. You can load the workspace when you launch the application or you can change it in app. When you are in workspace, if you are searching for files, you will not see anything that is possibly in the database but not attributed to the workspace. Additionally, each workspace could have its own settings attributed to it, for example color scheme.

The thing with calibre and Obsidian is that they use a local directory with all your files so I think that makes virtual libraries easier. It's just a completely different directory. However my application does not work that way, it is all in the database without having to change any files locally.

For example, I am working with ebook files and the main table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ebooks
 (
     "id"                 INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     "name"               TEXT NOT NULL,
     "author"             TEXT DEFAULT 'N/A',
     "genre"              TEXT DEFAULT 'N/A',
     "path"               TEXT NOT NULL,
     "ext"                TEXT NOT NULL,
     "pages"              INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
     "size"               INTEGER NOT NULL,
     "folder"             TEXT NOT NULL,
     "summary"            TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
     "time_added"         DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (Datetime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'localtime')),
     "last_modified"      DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (Datetime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'localtime')),
     UNIQUE("path"),
     UNIQUE("name")
  );
```

I have provided the table for more context. I could probably add a single field called "vault" and always filter based on the vault. Perhaps there is a more optimal database design?

Comment: You won't ever store actual files in the database though, right?...just references to the files' locations it appears? Where do those files actually live?

Comment: @J.D. The files actually live on the local hard drive. I only store references to those files.